# Pointer act like local varible and didn't keep it's modifiy in function

Tags: c

I have a pointer,it points to A,
I pass  this pointer into a function ,in the function ,pointer changed and pointer to B ,
When function end,the pointer value just restore back and pointer to A,that's why?

```
int device_num = 0;
int display_devices_size = 3;
DISPLAY_DEVICE* display_devices = (DISPLAY_DEVICE*)malloc(sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE) * display_devices_size);
get_display_devices(display_devices,&display_devices_size,&device_num);

void get_display_devices(DISPLAY_DEVICE* display_devices, int* display_devices_size, int* device_num)
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE d;
    d.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
    while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, *device_num, &d, 0))
    {
        //After the first call to EnumDisplayDevices DispDev.DeviceString contains graphic card's name. 
        //After the second call DispDev.DeviceString contains monitor's name.
        if (*device_num >= *display_devices_size)
        {
            DISPLAY_DEVICE* temp = (DISPLAY_DEVICE*)realloc(display_devices, (*display_devices_size) * sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE) * 2);
            if (temp != NULL)
            {
                display_devices = temp;
                *display_devices_size = *display_devices_size * 2;
            }
        }
        display_devices\[(*device_num)\] = d;
        (*device_num)++;
    }

}
```

Details as below screenshot:
[before function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k59m4.png)
[in function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uupp.png)
[after function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtJW7.png)

Comment: The pointer acts as a local variable because it is a local variable. By the way your function has undefined behaviour because it does not return anything.

Comment: @n.m. how can i pass it as a pointer? I do not want to get the value by return

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the pointer you need to pass the address of the pointer, not the contents of it. Your code is allocating a new pointer in the subroutine, but this has no effect on the original pointer. Edited code below - I have not checked that this compiles, but you can see the changes.

```
int device_num = 0;
int display_devices_size = 3;
DISPLAY_DEVICE* display_devices = (DISPLAY_DEVICE*)malloc(sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE) * display_devices_size);

// Pass the ADDRESS of display_devices

get_display_devices(&display_devices,&display_devices_size,&device_num);

// Function takes a pointer to a pointer as the first argument.

DISPLAY_DEVICE* get_display_devices(DISPLAY_DEVICE** display_devices, int* display_devices_size, int* device_num)
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE d;
    d.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
    while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, *device_num, &d, 0))
    {
        //After the first call to EnumDisplayDevices DispDev.DeviceString contains graphic card's name.
        //After the second call DispDev.DeviceString contains monitor's name.
        if (*device_num >= *display_devices_size)
        {
            DISPLAY_DEVICE* temp = (DISPLAY_DEVICE*)realloc(*display_devices, (*display_devices_size) * sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE) * 2);
            if (temp != NULL)
            {
                *display_devices = temp;
                *display_devices_size = *display_devices_size * 2;
            }
        }
        (*display_devices)[*device_num] = d;
        (*device_num)++;
    }

}
```

Comment: And I will add that even with the changes, this is ugly code. Rather than allocating memory both before and inside the function, it would be better for the function to build a list then allocate a clean copy and return it.

Comment: Hi clyde ,thanks for your help ,I admit this is not a good code and I have knew what you mean ,display_devices is not a pointer what I expect ,I need get it's address by & and use it's address

Answer (score 0):

This function does not return a value, so it should be of type `void`.

When you declare a pointer variable (in this case, DISPLAY_DEVICE*), the memory that is allocated for it is sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE*), not sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE).  This memory is what is referred to by the name 'display_devices' in the caller.

`realloc` can change the address pointed to (if it can't resize the argument memory block, it allocates new memory and deallocates the old memory).  As a result, this function should take a pointer to what is referred to as 'display_devices' in the caller, so that it can change that memory location.

The function prototype should be:

`void get_display_devices(DISPLAY_DEVICE** display_devices, int* display_devices_size, int* device_num)`

and it should be called as

`get_display_devices(&display_devices,&display_devices_size,&device_num);`

In addtion, all references to 'display_devices' in the called function should be changed to *display_devices, to dereference the value of that memory location to the new allocation.  All the references to display_devices_size should stay the same.

n.b.: I'm not even approaching what the function is supposed to do, I'm only answering the question you asked about the pointer manipulation.  It appears that you will need a lot more work on it before you get it to do what you want it to.

Comment: Hi sjcaged, I have know where the mistake is ,in DISPLAY_DEVICE* display_devices, display_devices should be regarded as a value ,not a pointer to pass in ,thanks for your help and code woks now